# Specify client.id per KafkaTemplate

Tags: spring-kafka

I know that it is possible to define `client.id` for each `@KafkaListener`.

Is it possible to define `client.id` for each `KafkaTemplate`?

It is easier to read the kafka-logs, if I can define the `client.id` per `KafkaTemplate` instead of relying on Spring assigning a suffix to each producer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Kafka doesn't assign any `client.id` into the `Producer` it creates:

```
protected Producer<K, V> createKafkaProducer() {
    return new KafkaProducer<K, V>(this.configs, this.keySerializer, this.valueSerializer);
}
```

Unless you provide one via `ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG` into those mentioned `configs`.

So, for each your `KafkaTemplate` you need to declare a separate `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` and share common properties via `Map<String, Object> configs`, but use unique `ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG` for each instance.

Alternatively you can implement your own `ProducerFactory` to populate a unique `ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG` each time its `createProducer()` is called.

Comment: I did not look into it, I just assumed it was Spring which handled the client.id. Is there any planned feature for producer client-id as you did for `@KafkaListener` with `clientIdPrefix` ?

Comment: Well, we don't: never raised. Feel free to add an issue on the matter and we definitely can  consider to add a `clientIdPrefix` into the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory`!

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.

Comment: The `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` only serves up a single producer used by all `KafkaTemplate`s -  unless you are using transactions, in which case it caches them. We could add the same suffix as the transaction id suffix in that case. The use of a single producer is recommended by the Kafka javadocs.